# Skipping sending one of the method parameters in Junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am calling one public method in my JUnit and skipping call to private method which is being called by public one.

```
SampleService sampleServiceSpy = Mockito.spy(sampleService); // I have reference to it through @InjectMocks

String str = Mockito.doReturn("Hiii").when(sampleServiceSpy ).sendRequestToAnotherComponent(<ARG1>,"?",<ARG3>);

String res = sampleServiceSpy.processRequest(<ARG1>, <ARG2>);
```

Here `processRequest()` is public method and private method is `sendRequestToAnotherComponent()` which I am skipping but problem is this method expects second argument as directory path which is random UUID generated differently every-time so I can't mock it. (Shown as `?` in sample code)

Is there any way I can pass any value and can skip this method?

I checked `Mockito.anyString()` is used to create mock objects and hence can't use it for this test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question - use matchers - for example:

```
 Mockito.doReturn("Hiii").when(sampleServiceSpy).sendRequestToAnotherComponent(eq(<ARG1>),any(UUID.class), eq(<ARG3>));
```

But instead of attempting to mock the method of the class that is being tested, inject a mock of the other component.  That way, the test can `verify()` the other component was invoked.

Comment: That worked, I was earlier not using Matchers with all arguments which looks like a Thumb rule. Thanks Andrew for help.